# CustomStyle and textColor props of @react-native-community/datetimepicker doesn't work

Tags: react-native

I'm using *DateTimePicker* imported from *@react-native-community/datetimepicker* on **iOS 14.5**.
I'm using the time mode (mode={'time'}) of the DateTimePicker and I want to modify the default style from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

So I tried by putting *textColor* as props and after by using the *customStyles* props but it never worked.

How can I change the default style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved by putting the props display={'spinner'} in the DateTimePicker.
In this way the props textColor has worked.